# Proof by minimum counter example

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I need to prove that $n^4-n^2$ is divisible by 12 by minimum counter example. I understand the process but I don't understand how we arrive at m>=7. I have seen different proofs but I still don't know how to decide which value is the smallest that I can use.[image]

Comment: They just check it when $n$ is from 1 to 6.

Comment: I know but, why not check it between 1 and 3.
Why do they stop at 6

Comment: Because the rest of their argument they replace $m$ by $k+6$ , so they need 6 base cases to cover the six residue classes mod 6.

Comment: One reason is that this is very straightforward to do so for $n<7$ ... The other is stated just above!

Answer (score 1):

$$(12-m)^{2r}=m^{2r}-2rm^{2r-1}12+\cdots+(12)^{2r}\equiv m^{2r}\pmod{12}$$ for integer $r>0$

$$\implies(12-m)^4-(12-m)^2\equiv m^4-m^2\pmod{12}$$

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you are doing and why you are doing it?

Comment: @user120767, If $m=5\implies12-m=7\implies$ if $12\mid(5^4-5^2)\iff12\mid(7^4-7^2)$ etc.

Comment: Yes but how does that tell me that I need to use a number greater or equal to 7 to not get stuck during the proof and have to use a lemma

Comment: @user120767, For $12,$ we need to check for $m$ such that $m\le12-m\iff m\le6$

Answer (score 1):

Expand the expression $(k+6)^4 - (k+6)^2$. The first power contributes $k^4$ plus additional terms (call these $A$) and the second term contributes $k^2$ plus additional terms (call these $B$). Now check whether $A$ and $B$ are perhaps divisible by $12$. If they are, then $k^4 - k^2$ is **not** divisible by 12, since you assumed that $m^4 - m^2$ is **not** divisible by 12. However, $k < m$, so now you have found a smaller counterexample.

Comment: but how do you know that you need to start with k+6. Do I just try k + n for n=1,2,3,4... until I know what to use

Comment: The exercise gave you this hint and you should use it. If you do with with $k+5$ instead of $k+6$ (for example), then you will not be able to show the statement. Write everything down for $k + 6$, then see whether all arguments still work for $k+5$. You can also try $k+4$ etc.. You will always get stuck somewhere if you choose these smaller numbers.

Comment: I know that I will get stuck. But I didn't have a hint it said prove this by minimum counter example. What I posted is just the answer form the solution manual

Comment: What other examples have you seen where a proof was done by minimum counterexample? Did they always work the exact same way, or was there some parameter that you had to adjust, such as the 6 in this case?

Comment: I always had to find the minimum counter example and then do the rest. For smaller numbers it's obvious if I substitute but the book does it in a different way and I don't understand the reasoning behind it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g45m76z1ouar3a1/Screenshot%202014-11-25%2010.38.07.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g45m76z1ouar3a1/Screenshot%202014-11-25%2010.38.07.png?dl=0
For example this

Comment: The book example says some thing like $m = 1$ is not a counterexample and $m = 2$ isn't either, so let's say $m \ge 3$. Then it turns out that if you assume $m = k+2$, the technique works. But if the technique didn't work for $m = k+2$, you would try $m = k+3$ next, and so on. That is what you have to do here as well. And that is how you sometimes have to construct proofs.

Answer (score 1):

They are basically showing (or telling you to show) that if $12\not\mid(m^4-m^2)$, then $12\not\mid (k^4-k^2)$, where $k=m-6$.  This says that the minimal positive counterexample, *if there is one*, must be among the numbers $1\le m\le6$, since these are the only positive numbers for which $m-6$ is *not* positive (and thereby a smaller positive counterexample).  That's why they start be showing that none of those numbers is a counterexample.